# Multiple application/json for same http POST request

Tags: rest, http, post

I am designing a REST API for incident reporting. There are are three state for one incident. i.e investigation,resolved and postmortem.

I use uri for incident resource as

```
 /incident/{incident_id}/{status}
```

Here incident_id denotes unique id of an incident and status denotes state of an incident.

User can create new incident(this is in investigation state) using

```
 POST - /incident
```

Say uri  after creating incident is

```
/incident/123
```

The applicatoin/json which is needed to be send with POST request to create resolved state and postmortem state of an incident are different.

Then there are two application/json for same uri.

I don't need change uri to

```
 POST -/incident/investigation/{incident_id}
 POST -/incident/resolved/{incident_id}
 POST -/incident/postmortem/{incident_id}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify _Now I want to post two application/json for resolved and postmortem states. But I can't use two post requests for same uri._?

Comment: When some one report a resolved state or postmortem state of an incident, jsons sent with POST request are different.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you want to achieve with such level of details. Can you please try to provide a concrete example? Also, please read your question _again_ and ask yourself if, anyone without a prior context would be able to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application/json which is needed to be send with POST request to create resolved state and postmortem state of an incident are different.

So there are two common answers here.

One is that the POST endpoint for the resource inspects the JSON object to figure out which request was made by the client, and then does the right thing.

The more mature version of this same idea is to use a different Content-Type to distinguish the json documents.  That is to say, if you define an `application/vnd.resolved+json` schema and an `application/vnd.postmortem+json` schema, then the client reports in the http headers which form of message it is sending to you.

```
POST /incident/12345
Content-Type: application/vnd.resolved+json

{ "resolved" : { ... } }


POST /indicdent/12345
Content-Type: application/vnd.postmortem+json

{ "post-mortem" : { ... } }
```

[RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838) describes the protocols for registering new media type formats, as well as reserving several namespaces for unregistered types.